# How to show commands details in sbt?

Tags: sbt

In sbt `commands` displays a list with a default non-descriptive toString

```
> commands
[info] List(sbt.SimpleCommand@46fb833a, sbt.SimpleCommand@2a64793e, sbt.SimpleCommand@2a53eb30, sbt.SimpleCommand@6b75b205)
```

How I could iterate over the list and display a name of the commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1998), which [will be fixed](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/2000) in 0.13.9.

---

As a stop gap you can do something like this in `consoleProject`:

```
commands.eval map { c =>
  ReflectUtilities fields c.getClass get "name" map { f =>
    f setAccessible true
    f get c toString
  } getOrElse c.toString
}
```